# Is there a way to instantiate a desired number of objects in Delphi, without iterating?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I think that C++ supports something on the lines of :

```
Object objects[100];
```

This would instantiate a 100 objects, right? Is it possible to do this in Delphi (specifically 2007)? Something other than:

```
for i:=0 to 99 do
  currentObject = TObject.Create;
```

or using the `Allocate` function, with a passed size value a hundred times the `TObject` size, because that just allocates memory, it doesn't actually divide the memory and 'give' it to the objects.
If my assumption that the c++ instantiation is instant rather than under-the-hood-iterative, I apologize.

Comment: I don't think you can simply say "TObject ObjList[100];" and you have created a 100 TObject's, you only have a list of 100 pointers that should be initialized to NIL|null and/or assigned an object to an item in list, so I think there's no quick way.

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo ok, maybe not the best example, but I still think a "one-line" instantiation of multiple objects is possible in c++. Waiting for more comments.

Comment: Any such syntax is likely to be sugar sprinkled on top of iterative instantiation.  Is there a reason you need syntax like that, rather than iterating?

Comment: @Goran_Mandic each TObject decendant needs to be "initialized" by calling it's constructor, otherwise it's not a real valid "object"

Comment: @LarryLustig I thought so too. The reason.. hoping for a performance boost, I guess?

Comment: Where would the performance boost come from? If the objects need to be created, they need to be created. If you want to avoid heap allocation, use a value type rather than a reference type.

Comment: You'll still have to pay for the instantiation of the all the objects. no matter how that instantiation is triggered.  The resources consumed by the loop are minimal.  If performance is a problem and the objects are relatively simple, consider using Delphi records instead.

Comment: If you really want to do this, just use an Array of Records and you don't have to create them all.

Comment: `TObject* data[100];` in c++ allocates only array of pointers to objects. Anyway, you have to create object instances using `data[i] = new TObject();` syntax (or somethink like that) as you do in Delphi, or any other language;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was imprecise. I'm using a profiler to analyze my program and I keep seeing a lot of instantiation calls of the same type. I really don't know where the bottleneck is so, I guess I was just "shooting in the dark" by trying to create objects all at once. 
Vlad - didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @Vlad: yes, C++ **does** support `Object objects[100]`, provided that `Object` is **not** a `TObject` descendant. `TObject` must be allocated on the heap, that is a Delphi requirement.  Nothing else in C++ has that requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is impossible because

- Delphi does not support static (stack allocated) objects.
- Delphi objects do not have default constructors that can be automatically invoked by compiler.

So that is not a lack of 'sugar syntax'.

---

For the sake of complete disclosure:

- Delphi also supports legacy 'old object model' (Turbo Pascal object model) which allows statically allocated objects;
- Dynamic object allocation itself does not prevent automatic object instantiation syntax, but makes such a syntax undesirable;
- Automatic object instantiation syntax is impossible because Delphi does not have default constructors: Delphi compiler never instantiate objects implicitly because it does not know what constructor to call.

Comment: I suppose asking for proof of this is ludicrous. I'll take your word, thanks!

Comment: It's true that you cannot do what you want, but I don't think the reasoning in this answer is accurate. There's no reason why you could not implement a language extension that supported automatic instantiation of objects that lived on the heap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - notice the second point. Delphi compiler never instantiate objects - it does not know what constructor to call.

Comment: I would HATE any extension to Delphi that violated that rule. We create 'em and we free 'em, and we like it that way.  Anybody who wants to start down the path to what the OP suggests is heading down the path towards managed languages, a path I hope Delphi never goes down.

Comment: @Serg The second point is valid, but the first point seems not to be.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The (pseudo) C++ syntax in the question assumes static objects. I agree with Warren, such a language extension for dynamically allocated objects is a nonsense.

Comment: @Serg Warren just said that he didn't want it to happen. I think I'd agree. I'm just saying that the lack of support for stack allocated objects is not a limitation in the context of the question. Also I think *static* is the wrong term. Don't you mean *automatic*?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - are you trolling :) ?

Comment: @Serg No I'm not. If Delphi had default constructors then a bit of sugar would get you home. It would be a bad idea, but it's not impossible.

Comment: Delphi does have default constructors as of XE3.

Comment: @NickHodges - what is default constructor for `TForm` class in XE3?

Comment: @Nick: Reference? I can't find this mentioned in the XE3 docs.

Comment: I was imprecise.  Delphi has class constructors which basically are default constructors.  Do a grep on the XE3 source for "class constructor" and you'll see them in action.

Comment: I realize now my understanding of how the whole object-oriented paradigm works isn't quite clear. Thanks for all the comments and the edit, guys. But I guess it wasn't a totally useless question, since it sparked a discussion.

Comment: @Nick No, class constructors are different. They are used to instantiate classes. Default constructors instantiate instances. Class constructors were introduced years and years ago, not in XE3.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Nope, you have missed nothing. There is nothing. Nick is confused.

Comment: @Serg Would it be possible to allocate a fixed amount of memory and then instantiate N objects inside THAT allocated memory? I suspect this would be faster than allocating chunk by chunk.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic: yes but I don't know how to free these N objects correctly - I never did it because I never need it.

Answer (score 5):

While you can't do what you want using objects, if your objects are relatively simple, you may be able to get what you want by using an array of records.

Records in Delphi can have properties (including setters and getters), and class and instance methods.  They are created automatically when declared, so declaring an array of them will create them all without iterating.

For more info: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Records_.28advanced.29.

(I'm not sure when the new functionality was added to Delphi, it may well be after the 2007 version).

Comment: in bds 2006 records already can have methods.If someone would replace `object` to `thingy` in the question this would be the answer.

Comment: This might help. Will look into it on Monday. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any non-hacky way to do this besides iterating:

```
var
  MyObjects: array[0..99] of TMyObject;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 99 do
    MyObjects[i] := TMyObject.Create;
end;
```

Comment: That's all well and correct, but it's the opposite of what I asked for :)

Comment: @Goran: No, it's the answer to `Is it possible to do this in Delphi (specifically 2007)?` amended with some **valid** Delphi syntax. :-)

Comment: No, Uli, it's not the answer to that. In that question, the word *this* referred to the task of allocating lots of objects *without iterating*. Your answer ignores that detail and is essentially no different from the Delphi code already given in the question. The correct answer to the question is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

That declaration wouldn't create 100 objects, it would just give you an array of 100 object references that point to nothing useful.

Creating an object is a two step process. The first step is allocating memory (which your code also doesn't), the second step is calling the constructor (Create method) to initialize that memory, create additional objects, etc, etc.

The allocation part can be done without the loop, but the constructor needs to be called to intialize each instance.

Many VCL classes don't have an additional constructor. They just have the empty constructor that does nothing. In that case, there is no need to call it.

For instance, to fetch an array of stringlists, you can use the following code, [adjusted from this example](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showpost.php?p=250168&postcount=17):

```
type
  TStringListArray = array of TStringList;v
var
  Instances: array of Byte;

function GetStringLists(Number: Integer): TStringListArray;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Allocate instance memory for all of them
  SetLength(Instances, Number * TStringList.InstanceSize);
  // Zero the memory.
  FillChar(Instances[0], Length(Instances), 0);
  // Allocate array for object references.
  SetLength(Result, Number);

  for i := 0 to High(Result) do
  begin
    // Store object reference.
    Result[i] := @Instances[i * TStringList.InstanceSize];
    // Set the right class.
    PPointer(Result[i])^ := TStringList;
    // Call the constructor. 
    Result[i].Create;
  end;
end;
```

And to get an array of 100 stringlists:

```
var
  x: TStringListArray;
begin
  x := GetStringLists(100);
```

So while this procedure may save you a neglectable amount of time, and may theoretically be more memory-efficient (less fragmentation), you will still need the loop. No easy way out.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but you need also some non-trivial finalization code for above `TStringListArray`. You cannot call `StringList[I].Free`.

Comment: I though I was clear in my answer that this is not a way you should always create your objects. You will probably never need this solution as it doesn't make it easier and only makes it marginally more efficient. However it does show how an object is created and why just allocating an `array[100] of TObject` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @Serg You're at least partially right. I think the returned array isn't a problem. It will exist as long as you keep a reference to it. Same goes for the Instances array, which contains the instance data. Instances shouldn't have been a local variable, though, because memory would be released as soon as the function exits. I've moved the array to global scope now, but to really use this code, you should probably have a class that manages those arrays.

Comment: I doubt you can free a single TStringList object - I don't know what FastMM reaction will be.

Comment: +1 I'm leaving work now, so I have no time to try this out, but it looks good at a first glance. Thanks @GolezTrol

Comment: @Serg Damn, you're right. Calling x[20].Free gives an instant access violation. :s This is not easily solved. You cannot call Free or Destroy. You can call CleanupInstance, but it doesn't call the overridden destructor that TStringList has.

Comment: I fail to understand why a simple `SetLength(x, 100)` (x is `TStringListArray`) will not allocate an array of 100 `TStringList`s. I'm still staring at this code trying to figure out why this "hack" is needed.

Comment: @Kobik An object variable (var x: TStringList) is actually a *pointer* to an instance of a TStringList. The pointer is 4 bytes (assuming Win32), but it points to (contains the address of) a buffer of about 56 bytes (Delphi 2007) that contains information about the TStringList itself, (which may include pointers as well, like a pointer to its array of items). SetLength(x, 100) just gives you an array of pointers that point to **nil** (because SetLength initializes them to nil). There are no instances whatsoever, just references.

Comment: When you allocate and zero the array of bytes, you got the space for the instances, but nothing else. If the object itself has pointers too (like, again, the array of items), you most still call Create (only as an instance method) to initialize those parts of the object. That's why you always need to call the constructor, even if you allocate all instance space at once.

Comment: What I meant is that after `SetLength` will `x[0] := TStringList.Create;` not create an instance of `TStringList`?

Comment: @kobik Sure, it will. If you call TObject.Create, you get an object, but the question seemed to be if it is possible to create 100 object without calling TObject.Create 100 times. The short answer to that is 'No', the longer answer, well, my answer.

Comment: Well, isn't your code calling Result[i].Create 100 times? so: `SetLength(x, 100);`, `for i := 0 to High(x) do x[i] := TStringList.Create;` will not create the same array? Maybe I need to ask my own question on SO... :)

Comment: It will have similar results. Only difference is that the allocation is done in one go, which may give you a little performance gain. There's text inbetween the code that explains this, but I can't stress enough that it's not your regular production code, and you shouldn't use this code unless in very specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is **somewhat** possible in Delphi (but is not very practical in a Delphi environment, unless you are writing a custom memory manager).  Creating an object instance is a two-step process - allocating memory for the object, and constructing the object's members inside of that memory.  There is nothing requiring the memory of a given object to be allocated individually.  You can allocate a larger block of memory and construct multiple objects inside of that block, taking advantage of a feature of Delphi that calls a constructor like a normal method if it is called from an instance variable instead of a class type, eg:

```
var
  objects: array of Byte;
  obj: TSomeClass;
begin
  SetLength(objects, 100 * TSomeClass.InstanceSize); 
  FillChar(objects[0], 0, Length(objects));
  for i := 0 to 99 do
  begin
    obj := TSomeClass.InitInstance(@objects[i * TSomeClass.InstanceSize]));
    obj.Create;
  end;
  ...
  for i := 0 to 99 do
  begin
    obj := TSomeClass(@objects[i * TSomeClass.InstanceSize]);
    obj.CleanupInstance;
  end;
  SetLength(objects, 0);
end;
```

This is not much different than what C++ does behind the scenes when declaring an array of object instances, only C++ supports declaring the array statically and it will call the constructors and destructors automatically, whereas Delphi does not support that.

There are a number of third-party implementations that allow you to allocate objects on the stack or in user-defined buffers, such as:

[Objects on the Stack: A Delphi Relic](http://rmarsh.com/2005/08/28/objects-on-the-stack-a-delphi-relic/)

[Allocate objects on stack, at specified memory address, or through any memory manager](http://www.kbasm.com/delphi-stack-local-object.html)

Just to name a couple.

Comment: New memory that is allocated with `SetLength()` for a dynamic array is not guaranteed to be zero in older Delphi versions. It doesn't hurt to zero it manually.

Comment: Really? Which versions don't zero it?

Comment: According to D7 doc: "For a long-string or dynamic-array variable, SetLength reallocates the string or array referenced by S to the given length. Existing characters in the string or elements in the array are preserved, but the content of newly allocated space is undefined. The one exception is when increasing the length of a dynamic array in which the elements are types that must be initialized (strings, Variants, Variant arrays, or records that contain such types). When S is a dynamic array of types that must be initialized, newly allocated space is set to 0 or nil."

Comment: I just checked the implementation, though.  New memory is always zero-initialized.  Just goes to show you cannot always rely on documentation alone.